# Dart | Flutter Package: How to update a Packge Not allowing my development to make progress?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-dependencies

The Following Package has not been updated:
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/tts 
I am getting the same error. 
Is there any way I can update or fix this issue on my side to continue https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/tts#-analysis-tab-

```
Running flutter packages pub upgrade failed with the following output:

ERR: The current Dart SDK version is 2.1.0-dev.1.0.flutter-69fce633b7.

Because tts requires SDK version >=1.8.0 <=2.0.0, version solving failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependency_overrides:
  tts: ^1.0.1
```

until `tts` is updated to support Dart 2 final.

Comment: tts should be in quote. Will using `"tts":any` also do the trick?

Comment: There is no need to use quotes for the name. The version constraint needs to be in quotes when it contains spaces like `">= 1.0.0 <2.0.0"`. Using `any` is discouraged because it increases the time to find a compatible set of dependencies because it allows all existing versions. Narrow constraints are usually better.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. But it is okay to make use of it once and then get the version that works from the `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: Definitely okay to make use of it for that. It's just if your application grows and the list of dependencies as well it could lead to troubles.